# How to solve deadlock detected by sql server?

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

I'm facing a deadlock problem, the sql server detects it and return an exception because it chose a process as a victim. I would like to avoid this problem, I tried to change the isolation level to read uncommitted and also add indexes but this did not resolve the problems, here is report that describe the deadlock problem:

```
<deadlock>

 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process133b1e188" />
 </victim-list>

 <process-list>
  <process id="process133b1e188" taskpriority="0" logused="5236" waitresource="RID: 18:1:3545:209" waittime="1939" ownerId="13564317" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2020-12-18T18:15:14.250" XDES="0x1a064a3a8" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="23832" status="suspended" spid="71" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2020-12-18T18:15:14.280" lastbatchcompleted="2020-12-18T18:15:14.280" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.280" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="med" hostpid="123" loginname="med" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="13564317" currentdb="18" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="462" stmtend="592" sqlhandle="0x030012003d326d4a3bf62b0195ac000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"> UPDATE DEP SET name WHERE id = 2    </frame>
   </executionStack>
  </process>

  <process id="process133b1e558" taskpriority="0" logused="30956" waitresource="KEY: 18:72057766865403904 (8c1a6a11df48)" waittime="1957" ownerId="13563835" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2020-12-18T18:15:14.113" XDES="0x1a064b668" lockMode="S" schedulerid="2" kpid="32596" status="suspended" spid="68" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2020-12-18T18:15:14.263" lastbatchcompleted="2020-12-18T18:15:14.263" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.263" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="med" hostpid="123" loginname="med" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="13563835" currentdb="18" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="24" sqlhandle="0x0200000064dbc4257a329ecd9ef9f0056fe48ce548b17d2e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
SELECT * FROM Worker w WHERE (w.id =  @P0 )  </frame>
   </executionStack>
  </process>

 </process-list>

 <resource-list>
  <ridlock fileid="1" pageid="3545" dbid="18" objectname="DEP" id="lock185869680" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057766864551936">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process133b1e558" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process133b1e188" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </ridlock>
  <keylock hobtid="72057766865403904" dbid="18" objectname="Worker" indexname="worker_id" id="lock17d9fdb80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057766865403904">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process133b1e188" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process133b1e558" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
 </resource-list>

</deadlock>
```

Comment: **process133b1e188**  has an `X` lock on a key in "Worker" table and is waiting for a `U` lock on a rid in DEP table to perform  `UPDATE DEP SET name WHERE id = 2`. **process133b1e558** has an `X`  lock on a rid in DEP table and is waiting for a `S` lock on a key in "Worker" table to perform `SELECT * FROM Worker w WHERE (w.id =  @P0 )` - the locks they have acquired that are blocking each other were probably acquired in previous statements. It looks like you are using `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` option. Is this intentional? - you may be grouping statements into the same transaction unnecessarily

Answer (score 0):

Try reading about:

```
set deadlock priority high
```

You should use `high` or 10 for the session you don't want to be the victim.

And I would say isolation level read uncommitted is not a good choice.